# consume Services from core module in app.component

Tags: angular, injectable

Hi im new at angular 2 and Im trying to put in place all the things I have learned in angular.io.
The problem is that I have readed about the core module, services, injectables ... and

If I have lets say a core-module like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './services/logger.service';

@NgModule({
    exports: [
        //components
        LoggerComponent,
    ],
    declarations: [LoggerComponent],
    providers: [LoggerService],
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

and a simple app.module like:

```
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CoreModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        routerModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I use the LoggerService service exported for the core-module? i have to

```
import {LoggerService} from './core/services';
```

in my app.component? because in the contructor of app.component its not working

```
constructor(logger: LoggerService){}
```

what Im missing? thanks!

Comment: Angular is using hierarchical injection, if you need to use the service in a different module you'll have to list it as a provider as it is only in service in that module (and on down inside of it) where you have listed it as a provider.

At least, that's what I remember from the top of my head.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: I will look in to it. thanks

Comment: Hm, I have a plunker running and it looks like I'm wrong. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `ngModule` [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html#!#providers-anchor)

> providers : Provider[] Defines the set of injectable objects that are
>   available in the injector of this module.

In other words, providers will be internal to the module and not outwardly exposed. Further reading in the documentation shows that only directives/pipes/(components) are applicable to export/declare.

So, to resolve this, you would need to directly reference the service in your higher level module, **note that it will correctly use the singly instantiated service in your core module** which is pretty cool and breaks my expectation.

**app.module.ts**

```
import {LoggerService} from './core/services';

@NgModule({<...>, providers: [<...>, LoggerService]})<...>
```

If you are going to have a bunch of shared services than using a **[barrel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#!#B)** where you list all of them and do a one time import would be a reasonable approach.

Here's the functioning [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0qvxuzZKOSLIQggVqtJA?p=preview)

Comment: I was testing and found out that, if you **don't add the LoggerService to the providers:[]** in the app.module.ts works just fine. :). thanks

Comment: This is incorrect. It will result in duplicate service instances. You can leave the providers declaration in the core module.